# CSS BUTTON WITH ICON

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a div button with a icon, but the problem is i don't know how to do this, i have googled it, there are ways with bootstraps but i don't understand bootstraps, i tried with span, here is my code>>

```
html:

<a href="about.html" style="text-decoration:none"> <span class="icon" style="background:url(icon.png) no-repeat;
    float: left;
    width: 10px;
    height: 40px;"></span><div class="div">
<h2>CALL CUSTOMER CARE</h2>
</div></a>


css:


.div {




text-align: left;
width:81%;
line-height: 298%;


 opacity: .8;
margin-left:0%;
margin-bottom:0px;
 border-radius:7px;
 background-color: hsl(0, 69%, 22%) !important;
  background-repeat:repeat-x;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#b42121", endColorstr="#5e1111");
  background-image: -khtml-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#b42121), to(#5e1111));
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #b42121, #5e1111);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #b42121, #5e1111);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #b42121), color-stop(100%, #5e1111));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #b42121, #5e1111);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #b42121, #5e1111);
  background-image: linear-gradient(#b42121, #5e1111);
  border-color: #5e1111 #5e1111 hsl(0, 69%, 17%);
  color: #fff !important;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33);
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}



.div h2{
font-size: 100%;
margin:0px;
font-family: “HelveticaNeue-Light”, “Helvetica Neue Light”, “Helvetica Neue”, Helvetica, Arial, “Lucida Grande”, sans-serif;
text-shadow: 0.1em 0.1em 0.1em  #2B3856;
}






.icon {
    background: url(icon.png) no-repeat;
    float: left;
    width: 10px;
    height: 40px;
}
```

Comment: You do not understand Bootstrap?

Comment: no, i don't understand

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Talking about copy + pasting the code from the [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons-examples) and modify it.

Comment: actually i have already designed a div button, i just need to add the icon, and if i copy paste, the whole thing would have to start from the first, that's why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Omg! Format your code!

Icons by Bootstrap or Semantic are fonts, not images.
So if you want to place a image as an icon on a button you should do something like that:

```
button {
    background: url(youricon) no-repeat ....;
    padding-left: 25px;
}
```

It just places an image on the leftside of your button and idents your text.
Otherwise you should learn how bootstrap works (its really simple!)
For examples how it works with fonts you can take a look to W3C:
http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_icons.asp

Comment: ok, thanks for the advice

Answer (score 1):

A basic code for start up.

```css
.button {
    display:block;
    width:100px;
    padding:10px;
    color:#fff;
    background:#009999 url(https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-l8CnQ0Y9Gi8/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAACU/y9lfiMGjWLU/photo.jpg?sz=32) no-repeat right;
}
```

```html
<a class="button">Button</a>
```